# Mongoose deep/nested Model.populate() returning 'Undefined'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to use Mongoose's built-in `Model.populate()` method on the `Post` object to 1) get the reviews within that object, then 2) a nested `populate:{}` option inside there to get the `username` property of the `author` of the `review` by the `ObjectId` of the `User`.

I'm probably missing something really obvious and simple, but 5ish hours later I can't find it. I'm seeing that the original `populate()` is getting the `ObjectId` of the `author` from the `Review` object within the array inside the `Post`, but then it isn't using that `ObjectId` to find the `username` property of that `User` object, it instead returns `Undefined` so the ternary statement within my ejs file shows the username: "Anonymous" fallback.

Any help for what I'm missing would be appreciated.

Post Model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const postSchema = new Schema({
  title:String,
  price:Number,
  description:String,
  images: [
    {
      url: {
        type:String,
        default:'https://res.cloudinary.com/rgreenstreet/image/upload/v1578603203/surf_shop/post/149933_txhwtj.png'
      },
      public_id: String,
    }
  ],
  location: {
    formattedAddress:String,
    lat:Number,
    lng:Number
  },
  author:
    {
      type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref:'User'
    },
  reviews:[],
  averageRating:{
    type:Number,
    default:0
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Post',postSchema);
```

Review Model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const reviewSchema = new Schema({
    body:String,
    rating:Number,
    author:
        {
            type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref:'User'
        }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Review',reviewSchema);
```

User Model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema({
    username:String,
    email:String,
    image: {
        url: {
            type:String,
            default:'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/05/22/37/blank-profile-picture-973460_960_720.png'
        },
        public_id: String
    },
    isAdmin:{
        type:Boolean,
        default:false
    }
});

userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

module.exports = mongoose.model('User',userSchema);
```

"Show" route for Post:

```
        post = await Post.findById(req.params.id).populate({
            path:'review',
            options:{sort: {'_id':-1}},
            populate:{
                path:'author',
                model:'User'
            }
        });
        res.render('posts/show',{post, title: 'SurfShop - View '+post.title, page:'view_post' });
```

And in my ejs file I'm trying to populate in `review.author.username`:

```
<div class="review">
                <% post.reviews.forEach((review) => { %>
                    <p><%= review.body %> - <%= review.rating %> Stars<%= (review.author.username ? ' - '+review.author.username : ' - Anonymous') %></p>
                    <hr/>
                <% }); %>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. My `Post` model and route was set to embed new `Review` objects in their entirety within the `reviews[]` array within the `Post` object (as well as saving them separately in their own collection), rather than just the `ObjectId` referring to the `Review` object.

I didn't quite understand the [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate_multiple_documents) the first few times as basically stating:

> in order to use `.populate()`, you have to save the reference to
>   another document in the current document via its `ObjectId` rather
>   than embedding the whole document

So since I had the `Review` object stored, rather than just its `ObjectId`, the nested `populate()` method was trying instead to look into another collection via an `ObjectId` that wasn't there by itself (let me know or edit if this is clear as mud), and didn't have anywhere to go.

It's working well now, so hopefully this will help the next schmuck who can't find clarity in the docs right away.